# I can't print output in another text file

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    int word_count = 0, in_word = 0;
    char file_name[MAX_LEN];
    /* Pointer for both the file*/
        FILE *fpr, *fpw;
        /* Opening file INPUT.txt in “r” mode for reading */
      start:
      printf("Enter a file name: ");
      scanf("%s", file_name);
      fpr = fopen(file_name, "r");

    /* Ensure INPUT.txt opened successfully*/
    if (fpr == NULL)
        {
        system("cls");
        printf("Could not open the file %s\n", file_name);
        goto start;
        }
          while ((ch = fgetc(fpr)) != EOF) {
          {
            printf("%c",ch);
          }

        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\0' || ch == '\n') {
          if (in_word) {
            in_word = 0;
            word_count++;
                }
            } else {
            in_word = 1;
        }
      }
        printf("In the file %s:\n", file_name);
    printf("Number of words: %d.\n", word_count);
    /* Opening file OUTPUT.txt in “w” mode for writing*/
    fpw= fopen("OUTPUT.txt", "w");

    /* Ensure OUTPUT.txt opened successfully*/
    if (fpw == NULL)
    {
       puts("Output file cannot be opened");
    }

    /*Read & Write Logic*/
    while ((ch = fgetc(fpr)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(ch, fpw);
    }

    /* Closing both the files */
    fclose(fpr);
    fclose(fpw);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it not printing in the output.txt file? And how can I also print the words in the output file?

There must be a conflict between the while function before printing the input. Or maybe there is something reading before the output then having conflict with another one, when I remove the while function (count words) it shows the product in the output.

Comment: Please don't use labels and `goto` instead of loops.

Comment: Also note that [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. This is rather important for the comparison agains the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Please don't edit code out of your question now that you've gotten your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read from `fpr` until you reach `EOF`, then try to read from it *again*.

You need to `rewind` the file to the beginning for the second `fgetc()` loop to produce anything.

Comment: thank you I have resolved my issue. do you know how to program count words in write mode ?

Comment: @kilzah I am not sure what you are asking, but it's trivial to change your program so it counts words _and_ writes the output in a single pass over the input -- just update your first loop to _also_ write the output in addition to word counting.

Comment: thank you so much!